# RabbitMQ Performance with multiple consumers

Tags: c#, asp.net, rabbitmq

I'm developing a queue consumption method and testing performance with multiple consumers.

In research it is recommended to increase consumers to increase the processing capacity of the queue.

I did the following tests.

Queue with only 1 consumer, that's where I saw the highest transfer rate.

Queue with 1 channel and more than 5 consumers, the capture rate has dropped.

Queue with 1 consumer per channel, same result as before.

I'm working with only 1 worker to create all instances of consumers, should more than one worker be used per consumer to have the performance?

Do you have a suitable configuration to improve the performance of multiple consumers?

Follow my method

```
 public Task ConsumerRabbitMQAsync<T>(string queeue, int consumerNumber)
        {
            var manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            manualResetEvent.Reset();

            try
            {
                CreateConnection();
               

                for (int i = 0; i < consumerNumber; i++)
                {
                    var channel = _connection.CreateModel();

                    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queeue,
                                     durable: false,
                                     exclusive: false,
                                     autoDelete: false,
                                     arguments: null);


                    ConsumerQueeueAsync<T>(queeue, channel);
                }

                manualResetEvent.WaitOne();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async void ConsumerQueeueAsync<T>(string queeue, IModel channel)
        {
            var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);

            consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var body = ea.Body;

                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body.Span);

                    SendMessage<T>(message);

                    channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);

                    await Task.Yield();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    channel.BasicNack(ea.DeliveryTag, false, true);
                }
            };

            channel.BasicConsume(queue: queeue,
                                 autoAck: false,
                                 consumer: consumer);

        }
```

Comment: Why are you declaring `consumerNumber` amount of the same queue?

Comment: I do a for with the amount of consumers informed in the method call and create them within that for